# attribute!='value' jquery selection doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I have a `jQuery( "[attribute!='value']" )` jquery selection which works in all browsers except IE.I also tried `.not( "[name='value']" )` but no luck.

**JS:**

```
$("input[type=file]").not("[name='photo_1']").parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find(".label").remove();
```

what should I do?

**EDIT:**

```
$("input[name!='photo_1']").parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find(".label").remove();
```

Comment: What version of jQuery and IE do you use ?

Comment: I see no `!=` anywhere in your code...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9T43g/1/ tested in IE 8 and 9, seems to work

Comment: @dystroy, internet explorer 9

Comment: @meagar, I've tested it and doesn't work but i'll add it to my post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `.filter` might be the answer here:

```
$("input[type='file']").filter(function(){
    if($(this).attr('name') != 'photo_1'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find(".label").remove();
```